# How to add multiple values in one query to a PostgreSQL array?

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, postgresql

So if I have a Javascript array of strings, how do I append each element to a row in the Postgres text[] column? This is what I'm currently using, but it's not yielding the desired result (which is just making the text array in the column of {"1","2","3"}.

```
let addNumbers = 'UPDATE numTable SET column1 = array_append(columnName, ($1)) WHERE uid = ($2)'

let x = ["1","2","3"]
```

I'm querying to the db with

```
query(addNumbers, [x, uid]);
```

I've tried using array_append but this results in the column getting a value of

```
{"{\"1\",\"2\",\"3\"}"}
```

I'd prefer not to iterate and append each one individually because this'll obviously increase the number of database calls--any help is much appreciated!